# Индикация процесса на сервере в html-форме

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

В HTML-форме запускается кнопкой процесс на сервере, который занимает некоторое время.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы отображать ход процесса в этой форме.

С чем я столкнулся: при запуске процесса - все запросы к серверу "притормаживают" и ждут, пока завершится процесс, ход которого я и пытаюсь отображать. Я пробовал отображать в отдельном фрейме и даже в другом окне браузера. Все равно обновление останавливается и ждет завершения индицируемого процесса.

Буду благодарен за идеи.

Comment: Это проблема того что ваш сервер работает в "однопоточном" режиме - один запрос до окончания работы, смотрите в настройках сервера

Comment: @daniel-protopopov Речь  о web-сервере?

Comment: Да, я говорю о веб-сервере

Comment: Запущено через `artisan serve`? Это однопоточный режим для разработки. Настройте нормально: php-fpm + nginx, как это сделать написано в интернетах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо  добрым людям (Daniel Protopopov и Total Pusher), разобрался:  дело в настройках веб-сервера. Там нужно включить многопоточность - и всё заработает.